# Django Serve .XLSX File and force download

Tags: python, django

I'm currently using openPYXL in order to open a template file within Django

```
    module_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)  # get current directory
file_path = os.path.join(module_dir, fileName)
username = request.user.username
workbook = load_workbook(file_path)
worksheet = workbook.active
```

The file is then edited, and saved under a different name(This works fine, I can open the created file and it contains the information desired), however what I'm struggling with is serving this file to the user, I've tried various techniques such as shown below

```
workbook.save('EvalofSelf1.xlsx')
response = HttpResponse()
file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__name__)), 'EvalofSelf1.xlsx')
response['X-Sendfile'] = file_path
response['Content-Type'] = 'mimetype/submimetype'
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s.xlsx' % 'DownloadedEval'
```

All of which serve a file as requested, but the file contains no actual data, is 0kb in size and unopenable, how can I serve up the created file from my Django project directory, retaining all information stored within it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not ever putting the file contents into the response, so naturally it is 0 bytes. `X-Sendfile` is for a completely different purpose - when you're redirecting to a static server - and needs a URL, not a file path, anyway.

```
file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__name__)), 'EvalofSelf1.xlsx')
response = HttpResponse(open(file_path, 'rb').read())
response['Content-Type'] = 'mimetype/submimetype'
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=DownloadedEval.xlsx'
```

Comment: Thanks, could you list the import needed for the open_file?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: The issue with the above solution, is i keep getting unicodeDecodeErrors, due to the nature of the template, is there a workaround that avoids this?

Comment: Updated with a possible fix - open in binary mode.

Comment: this one is good https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/365/  except FileWrapper is in wsgiref.util.FileWrapper right now

Comment: for some reason im receiving corrupted excel files after doing this.